# Can Ubuntu 14.04 be installed on ASUS Transformer Book Flip TP300LD-DW102D

Tags: 14.04, asus, hybrid

I am considering to purchasing ASUS Transformer Book Flip TP300LD-DW102D, and wondering whether Ubuntu 14.04 can be installed in this hybrid notebook.

It will be shipped with Windows 8, and can Ubuntu be installed alongside windows 8.

One more thing, this ASUS hybrid notebook doesn't have Ethernet port, just WiFi, if Ubuntu can be installed, how can I install the WiFi driver on it?

Since I can't connect to internet through Cable LAN. I need suggestion on this.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) We're sorry but AskUbuntu is not a forum but a Question&Answer site: It works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer.  When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas which becomes more unlikely the more questions you put into... well, one question!  ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions...

Comment: Have you successfully installed ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Ubuntu aside Windows on my TP300LD: installation process runs smoothly, it recognizes wifi card so you can download latest updates during installation.

Keep in mind: Asus doesn’t support Linux and uses proprietary hardware. Ubuntu runs well but cannot get maximum gain.

Thus:

- ATK (touchpad) is used as PS/2 mouse so you cannot use gesture (the biggest issue, on my opinion);
- several key on the keyboard aren't available;
- Fliplock or similar doesn’t exist;
- monitor doesn't rotate;
- monitor auto-backlight doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu offline (with the live cd).  After the installation you can connect to your wifi with ubuntu - if ubuntu does not find your wifi during the installation.